# upload and preview file before uploading replacing last image issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to upload image and previewing it one by one but it replace last image.
I want to keep adding up more and more images but only last image is showing in received $_FILES array

Keep all upload images in form and keep them previewing.

my code

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="add-gallary" name="filecollections[]">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        
    <div class="gallery"></div>

</form> 
<script>
$(function() {
var upload_count = 0;
    
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }

                // input.files.append(input.files[i]);


                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                upload_count++;
            }
        }

    };

    $('#add-gallary').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are the images getting replaced by the last one when you upload to backend OR when you preview one by one ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping on backend I only get one last image nothing else.And I need all uploaded images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why only last images is getting uploaded is that you are storing the images in an `array` because you have single file upload `input`.

If you want upload multiple images you have previewer on form submit you would need to store them in array i have named `imagesToUpload`

Once you have all the images previwed and ready to submit the form with images you have selected and previewed you have loop `forEach` through that array `imagesToUpload` and append those file data to `formData`.

You will then this formData to your backend and upload all the images on backend using `ajax` request.

Run snippet below to see that array is using `.push` function to store all your images you have previewed.

```js
$(function() {
  var upload_count = 0;

  //Store images in array
  var imagesToUpload = []

  var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

    if (input.files) {
      var filesAmount = input.files.length;

      for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(event) {
          $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
        }

        // input.files.append(input.files[i]);

        //Push images to array on preview                
        imagesToUpload.push(input.files[i])


        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        upload_count++;
      }
    }

  };

  $('#add-gallary').on('change', function() {
    imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    console.log(imagesToUpload)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="add-gallary" name="filecollections[]">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  <div class="gallery"></div>

</form>
```